# git local patch (or branch) management

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

My company uses atlassian stash to develop.  So, our normal development process is create a remote branch for whatever you're doing, push changes to the branch, and do a pull request.

However, many times I'd like to float several changes at a time.  For example, as I'm working on feature X, I expose a bug in Y.  I'd like to keep the changesets independent as I submit pulls.

I can think of a couple of brute force methods:

- Have multiple local repos for each fix, and, push them synchronously.
- Create tons of remote branches, and push in parallel.
- Use stash to hold my patch sets, and push synchronously.

But, there has to be an easier way.  I guess I'm looking for some kind of quilt, but one that is not ordered.  I'd like to keep my patchsets separate until ready for commit.

Suggestions?

Comment: Would a number of *local* branches work for you, and rebasing them against the 'main' branch as needed? If not, perhaps you could explain what you'd be missing with that approach so that we can understand your situation better.

Comment: I think that method would work.  But, I'm kind of new to git branches, so, I need to get more comfortable with rebasing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've listed some good solutions to your problem.

Sometimes when I don't want to introduce a change yet, i just don't add those files to my commit - just specify what files you want to add `git add filename`. I really only do this if I'm testing quickly - I suppose this could get messy quick.
When its time to pull again you may have a merge conflict if someone else touched that file you were working on.. but it should be pretty easy to reintroduce your code.

You can try [git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) - this will save your unfinished changes to a stack. You can reapply them whenever you want.

Also, if you're working on long-term enhancements or bugs - I would create another branch like Krüger mentioned.